# Why is my stub-resolve.conf missing?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, oracle-linux, systemd-resolved

I'd like to start using `systemd-resolved` on Oracle Linux 7.6.

I've installed `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-resolved`. I've enabled these services and I've disabled `network` and `NetworkManager`.

From the possible working modes I'd like to use `systemd-resolved` as a local resolver and for the compatibility reasons I'd like to link `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` which is supposed to point to `nameserver 127.0.0.53`.

However the `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` file is missing in my installation. Would you please be able to tell why? `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` is present though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, i am late to the party, but maybe this will help others.
I had the same problem, and actually, the `/run/systemd/resolv` directory was missing.

Then I realized that `systemd-resolved.service` was not running.  For some reason, it got disabled.

So I had to simply just bring it up again.

```
sudo systemctl enable --now systemd-resolved.service
```

Comment: This answer works for me, thank you so much!

Comment: Error: `Failed to enable unit: Unit file systemd-resolved.service does not exist.` What to do?!

Comment: Wow, finally issue resolved. For many days, i was looking for this. Thanks